# Traduction de "average human lifetime"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, science

> Estimate the number of breaths taken during an average human lifetime.

La traduction ci-dessous est-elle correcte ?

> Estimer le nombre de respirations au cours de la durée moyenne de vie d'un être humain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'adjectif « moyenne » ne qualifie pas simplement le mot « durée » mais le groupe « durée de vie », j'écrirai donc :

> Estimer le nombre de respirations au cours de la durée de vie moyenne d'un être humain.

voire même avec un impératif au début si on considère que l'on pose une question :

> Estimez le nombre de respirations au cours de la durée de vie moyenne d'un être humain.